# encoding problem?

Tags: c#, encoding

I want to get a picture from web, and turn that into a byte array. But there is something wrong reading the response. I suspect it caused by encoding modes.

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.waterfootprint.org/images/gallery/original/apple.jpg");
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Timeout = 10000;
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding);

            string responseBody = streamReader.ReadToEnd(); //always invalid characters here
            streamReader.Close();
            stream.Dispose();
            byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(responseBody); 
        }
```

I have tried other encoding ways, such as UTF7, Unicode, etc, but all in vain. Could someone tell me why? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding);
```

[`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) is a *TextReader* that reads characters from a byte stream in a particular encoding.

> StreamReader is designed for character
>   input in a particular encoding,
>   whereas the Stream class is designed
>   for byte input and output. Use
>   StreamReader for reading lines of
>   information from a standard text file.

In your case you receive raw bytes - You either need to work with the `Stream` directly, use a `BinaryReader` or a higher level abstraction.

```
        byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(responseBody);
```

The stream you are getting is not base64 encoded - it's a pure image byte stream, so just assign the bytes directly, easiest would be with a [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
using(WebClient wc = new WebClient())
byte[] buffer = wc.DownloadData("http://www.waterfootprint.org/images/gallery/original/apple.jpg");
```

[Base 64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is usually used when you must transmit binary data as ASCII text (i.e. as part of an XML CData element or SOAP in general) - but not if you want to transmit a binary file (i.e. an image) over HTTP.

Comment: but what if in the server end, the image is just returned in base64encoding: `return convert.FromBase64String(imageString);`

Comment: that would be weird - but hypothetically you could then just get the string using `wc.DownloadString()`, then use `Convert.FromBase64String()` to convert it back to a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

It comes back as binary, not base-64 encoded.  For example, if I change your code to create an image directly from the response stream, I see it appear in a PictureBox control.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.waterfootprint.org/images/gallery/original/apple.jpg");
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Timeout = 10000;
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            Bitmap b = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(response.GetResponseStream());
            pictureBox1.Image = b;
        }
    }
```